# Flows don't show up on demobench

Tags: corda

I wrote a simple cordapp based on cordapp-template-kotlin. I have one flow in it, and when I start the nodes using `build\nodes\runnodes.bat`, the flow is listed when I run `flow list` from the command line. When I start the same cordapp through `demobench`, however, the flow is not listed. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I think it's a bug which is in probably backlog. refer this: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3702

Comment: Yeah, I added that comment. The issue is caused by the fact that the template has three gradle projects, the main project, and two sub projects (cordapp, and cordapp-states or something like that). When you run `gradlew.bat jar` it builds the main app but places no code in the jar. It creates a separate jar for the sub projects which contains the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kid101 says, this is a Corda 3 bug referenced here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3702.